# Create multiple unique copies of an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, copy

I have a numpy array assigned to `a`

I want to to this

```
b = a.copy()
c = a.copy()
d = a.copy()
```

in one line. Is that possible without having to write "a.copy" 3 times ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you familiar with loops?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I don't see how that's possible in a basic loop.. except by using a dictionnary. What I mean is: I don't think it's possible to create variables on each iteration of a loop. Mind giving an example ?

Comment: You don't think it's possible to create variables in a loop? I suggest reviewing some course materials or tutorials on loops.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm sorry, I was just asking if there was a way to write a better version of the code above, without having the trouble of using dicts or ugly globals()...

Comment: I don't know what `globals()` has to do with this. Investigate two concepts: loops, and appending to a `list`. There are many resources on these that you will find by Googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it is possible, but I think the three separate assignment statements using `a.copy()` are the clearest way to do it.  I can read that code and know exactly what is happening.  With the following, I have to spend a few seconds figuring out what is going on...

- Use a list comprehension (@Pythonista also had this in a deleted answer):

  ```
  b, c, d = [a.copy() for _ in range(3)]
  ```
- Use `numpy.repeat`:

  ```
  b, c, d = np.repeat(a[None, ...], 3, axis=0)
  ```